# API does not allow origin when requesting from 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: javascript, api, axios, cross-domain

I'm currently developing a website on my localhost. A key component of the website must make requests to a third-party API (specifically https://api.commonstandardsproject.com/). The request is made via javascript running on the user's browser. However, when I attempt to run the following:

```
            var reqUrl = 'https://api.commonstandardsproject.com/api/v1/jurisdictions';
            axios.get(reqUrl, {
                headers: {
                    'Api-Key': "vZKoJwFB1PTJnozKBSANADc3"
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                var parsedResp = JSON.decode(response.data)
                this.jurisdictions = parsedResp
            }).catch((errors) => {
                console.log(errors)
            });
```

I receive a 401 from the API and an error stating that: `error: "Unauthorized: Origin isn't an allowed origin."`. Interestingly, I can access the API content fine (and without an API key) using just a browser or curl. When I check the origin of my request in the networks tab on chrome, it gives `127.0.0.1:8000`. I believe this is the locus of the error, though I am uncertain of how to resolve it.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly modified your code to print the result to the browser console.

```
var reqUrl = "https://api.commonstandardsproject.com/api/v1/jurisdictions";
axios
  .get(reqUrl, {
    headers: {
      "Api-Key": `MY API KEY`,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((errors) => {
    console.log(errors);
  });
```

I created an account and found I got the same results as you.

To get a successful response from the api I had to update my 'ALLOWED ORIGINS' in the sidebar of the https://commonstandardsproject.com/developers page to match the first part of the URL from the index.html file I was running in the browser.

E.g. the URL for the index.html I am running locally is:
http://10.0.1.159/index.html

I updated the ALLOWED ORIGINS to include the string
http://10.0.1.159

[Allow Origins example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCXRl.png)

You will have to add the local address for the page you are testing from in the ALLOWED ORIGINS section of the developer page for the commonstandardsproject where you are signed into your account. Make sure to hit the 'update origins' button after you have entered the correct URL.